# rotate an element over it's bottom axis instead of its center when using rotateX()

Tags: css, css-transforms, rotatetransform

I can't seem to get a div element to rotate around it's bottom edge. By default, rotateX(angle) makes the element rotate around it's center.

Here's a codepen: [Trying to flip div over bottom edge](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/qafsx)

I tried playing with the transform-origin property but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Set a `transform-origin` for the element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: In my question I said that I tried that but the combinations I used didn't work.

Comment: It appears to be something with the `:hover` state not being applied. If you manaully force the `:hover` state on the element, it animates even when `transform-origin` is applied. I'm testing in Chrome 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right on hovering, it's rotated (around X axis) and makes the `:hover` state inactive. It's very sensitive this way and may depend on different browsers. The solution is try using a placeholder (whose size and position are fixed while animating) wrapping your actual flip card:

**HTML**:

```
<div class='placeholder'>
 <div class="flipper forward">
   Hello
 </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.placeholder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;  
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.flipper {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid darkred;  
  //@include backface-visibility(hidden);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
  @include transition(-webkit-transform 2s);
  @include transform(rotateX(0deg));  
}
.placeholder:hover > div {
  @include transform(rotateX(180deg));
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzawn).

Answer (score 2):

Use transform origin

```
-webkit-transform-origin: $x $y;
-moz-transform-origin: $x $y;;
-o-transform-origin: $x $y;
transform-origin: $x $y;
```